# Version 4 of Azure App Service Deploy - *.deploy.cmd not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to release my application to Azure using Version 4 of Azure App Service Deploy and using publish profile for the connection. Unfortunately, the release always gets stopped at deployment stage with the following log:

> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1570167Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy to Azure
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1577464Z Task : Azure App Service Deploy
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1577875Z Description : Update Azure WebApp
>   Services On Windows, Web App On Linux with built-in images or docker
>   containers, ASP.NET, .NET Core, PHP, Python or Node based Web
>   applications, Function Apps, Mobile Apps, Api applications, Web Jobs
>   using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1578288Z Version : 4.1.7
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1578503Z Author : Microsoft Corporation
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:47.1578765Z Help : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
>
> **2018-06-05T13:46:48.5822489Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd**
>
> 2018-06-05T13:46:48.5857098Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy to Azure

I am lost what to do, because I can't find anything about any deploy.cmd file in the Azure deployment documentation. I have to use Version 4, which is currently in Preview mode, because deploying through a publish profile is my only option.

---

More info:

I am using `MSDeploy` as the web publish method in my publish profile.

Here are the debug logs (I have replaced some names with **xyz**, but I don't think that information is relevant here):

> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0003493Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=D:\a
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0033559Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0038896Z ##[debug]loading 
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0049663Z ##[debug]loading 
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0052788Z ##[debug]loading 
>   ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0056543Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONNECTIONTYPE
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0058753Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DEPLOYTOSLOTORASEFLAG
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0060382Z ##[debug]loading 
>   INPUT_EXCLUDEFILESFROMAPPDATAFLAG
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0061865Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_INLINESCRIPT
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0063426Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PACKAGE
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0066224Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILEPASSWORD
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0067906Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILEPATH
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0069224Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REMOVEADDITIONALFILESFLAG
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0070734Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_RENAMEFILESFLAG
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0072348Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SCRIPTPATH
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0075673Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SETPARAMETERSFILE
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0077762Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TAKEAPPOFFLINEFLAG
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0079810Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_USEWEBDEPLOY
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0081592Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_WEBAPPKIND
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0082955Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLTRANSFORMATION
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0084823Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_XMLVARIABLESUBSTITUTION
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0093697Z ##[debug]loading SECRET_PUBLISHPROFILEPASSWORD
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.0098888Z ##[debug]loaded 20
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.2771292Z ##[debug]agent.proxyurl=undefined
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.2771976Z ##
>   [debug]VSTS_ARM_REST_IGNORE_SSL_ERRORS=undefined
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.2772456Z ##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_b3b41228-
>   42cb-4f40-92e9-62eb4918f3a4_release_1_23_23_1
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3083885Z ##[debug]check path : 
>   D:\a_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-
>   48d9c1acdcb1\4.1.7\task.json
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3085278Z ##[debug]set resource file to: D:\a_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeployment_497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1\4.1.7\task.json
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3086246Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3221858Z ##[debug]ConnectionType=PublishProfile
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3224073Z ##[debug]WebAppKind=app
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3226659Z ##[debug]DeployToSlotOrASEFlag=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3227033Z ##[debug]VirtualApplication=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3229440Z ##[debug]Package=D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz.zip
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3229978Z ##[debug]GenerateWebConfig=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3230385Z ##[debug]WebConfigParameters=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3231041Z ##[debug]XmlTransformation=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3232525Z ##[debug]JSONFiles=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3234042Z ##[debug]XmlVariableSubstitution=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3236701Z ##[debug]UseWebDeploy=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3237236Z ##[debug]TakeAppOfflineFlag=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3238059Z ##[debug]RenameFilesFlag=false
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3238698Z ##[debug]AdditionalArguments=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3241554Z ##[debug]ScriptType=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3242705Z ##[debug]InlineScript=:: You can provide your deployment commands here. One command per line.
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3243214Z ##[debug]ScriptPath=D:\a\r1\a
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3243711Z ##[debug]DockerNamespace=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3244088Z ##[debug]AppSettings=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3245290Z ##[debug]StartupCommand=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3245776Z ##[debug]ConfigurationSettings=null
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3246285Z ##[debug]PublishProfilePath=D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3246989Z ##[debug]PublishProfilePassword=***
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3248921Z ##[debug]Predeployment Step Started
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3261147Z ##[debug]Finding files matching input: D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3261800Z ##[debug]Matching glob pattern: D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3262255Z ##[debug]Index of first wildcard: 10
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3262895Z ##[debug]find root dir: D:\a\r1\a\
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3267015Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\r1\a\'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3267947Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3269147Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3274196Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a\ (directory)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3281597Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core (directory)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3286601Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop (directory)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3290769Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz.zip (file)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3293516Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz - Web Deploy.pubxml (file)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3293935Z ##[debug]5 results
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3298091Z ##[debug]patternRoot: ''
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3298639Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3299997Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3300471Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3301015Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3301435Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3302184Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3302692Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3303074Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3303700Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3304333Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3305141Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3305619Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\a\r1\a***.pubxml'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3306098Z ##[debug]expanding braces
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3306668Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/r1/a/**/*.pubxml'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3307199Z ##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3338789Z ##[debug]1 matches
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3339828Z ##[debug]1 final results
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3446116Z ##[debug]Publish Profile: {"WebPublishMethod":["MSDeploy"],"ResourceId":["xyz"],"ResourceGroup":["xyz"],"PublishProvider":["AzureWebSite"],"LastUsedBuildConfiguration":["Release"],"LastUsedPlatform":["Any CPU"],"SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish":["xyz"],"LaunchSiteAfterPublish":["True"],"ExcludeApp_Data":["False"],"ProjectGuid":["0069d61c-2633-4e96-b9d4-c321827ff547"],"MSDeployServiceURL":["xyz"],"DeployIisAppPath":["xyz"],"RemoteSitePhysicalPath":[""],"SkipExtraFilesOnServer":["True"],"MSDeployPublishMethod":["WMSVC"],"EnableMSDeployBackup":["True"],"UserName":["xyz"],"_SavePWD":["True"],"_DestinationType":["AzureWebSite"],"TargetFramework":["netcoreapp2.0"],"SelfContained":["false"],"_IsPortable":["true"]}
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:35.3533911Z ##[debug][GET]http://xyz
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5376747Z ##[debug]App Service status Code: '200'. Status Message: 'OK'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5378242Z ##[debug]set AppServiceApplicationUrl=xyz
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5427498Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=AppServiceApplicationUrl;issecret=false;]xyz
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5428263Z ##[debug]Deployment Step Started
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5429986Z ##[debug]Performing the deployment of webapp using publish profile.
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5430570Z ##[debug]Finding files matching input: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz.zip
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5431099Z ##[debug]Finding files matching input: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5431796Z ##[debug]Matching glob pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5432803Z ##[debug]Index of first wildcard: 29
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5433444Z ##[debug]find root dir: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5433875Z ##[debug]findPath: 'D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5434698Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5435250Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5435763Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\ (directory)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5436284Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz.zip (file)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5436867Z ##[debug]  D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop\xyz - Web Deploy.pubxml (file)
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5437380Z ##[debug]3 results
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5437837Z ##[debug]patternRoot: ''
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5438564Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5439030Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5439519Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5439989Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5440436Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5440865Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5441291Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5463216Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'true'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5464910Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5465466Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5465958Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'undefined'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5466462Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5466937Z ##[debug]expanding braces
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5467383Z ##[debug]pattern: 'D:/a/r1/a/_CI .NET Core/drop/*.deploy.cmd'
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5467846Z ##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5468475Z ##[debug]0 matches
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5468869Z ##[debug]0 final results
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5469314Z ##[debug]No matching files were found with search pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5469846Z ##[debug]Deployment Failed with Error: Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5470406Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5536667Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5553501Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd
>
> 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5555471Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a_CI .NET Core\drop*.deploy.cmd 2018-06-06T09:08:36.5555917Z ##[debug]

Comment: You need to specify a web deploy package, not a batch file.

Comment: Which publish method you used to publish/deploy web app? (Check in publish profile) What's the detail setting of Azure App Service Deploy task? Can you provide the detail log here? (Add system.debug variable and set to true, then start release)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I have added requested information.

Comment: How do you generate the deployment package? is there deploy.cmd file in the necessary build artifact? It is generated by web deploy package publish method `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" /p:PackageTempRootDir=""`

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I am using VSTS Publish Build Artifacts task with `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` path. I also have a .NET Core task for publishing that comes before, with `--configuration debug --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` arguments. This setup does not produce a `deploy.cmd` file.

Comment: The publish task produces a zip file, but there is no `deploy.cmd` neither alongside the zip file nor inside it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to publish the web app through Web deployment package publish method in order to generate the necessary files (e.g. deploy.cmd):

1. Remove .NET Core build and publish task
2. Add Visual Studio Build task (`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped! Unfortunately I'm stuck somewhere else... I opened a follow-up question, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854434/version-4-of-azure-app-service-deploy-error-user-not-authorized-for-createapp