# Version 4 of Azure App Service Deploy - ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702164/version-4-of-azure-app-service-deploy-deploy-cmd-not-found). The answer in the original question helped me, but I am stuck somewhere else. As a reminder, I want to deploy my application using a publish profile. My web app in Azure has two subfolders inside wwwroot and one of them is called **backend**. I want to deploy my application to that folder. I am not sure why msdeploy wants to create anything, since the web app is already there - I just need to get the artifacts inside the **backend** folder.

Here is the relevant part of the log (with some names changed to **xyz**):

> 2018-06-14T09:19:25.0295238Z Start executing msdeploy.exe
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:25.0323018Z "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\drop\xyz.zip' -dest:auto,computerName="https://xyz.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=xyz/backend",userName="$xyz",password="***",authtype="basic",includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"D:\a\r1\a\artifacts\drop\xyz.SetParameters.xml"
>   -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:25.6154385Z Info: Using ID '89f1210b-39ba-4758-b7ee-76a06407a503' for connections to the remote server.
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.0800802Z Info: Creating application (Default Web Site)
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2012951Z ##[debug]rc:1
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2013216Z ##[debug]rc:1
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2013360Z ##[debug]success:false
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2013523Z ##[debug]success:false
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2073234Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2081930Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2082198Z ##[debug]{}
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2082470Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=D:\a\r1\a
>
> 2018-06-14T09:19:28.2083178Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP More Information: Could not
>   complete an operation with the specified provider ("createApp") when
>   connecting using the Web Management Service. This can occur if the
>   server administrator has not authorized the user for this operation.
>   createApp http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178034  Learn more
>   at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP.
>
> Error count: 1.

Comment: Have you specified the virtual application in the App Service's Application Settings?

Comment: Sounds like it thinks the app doesn't exist in IIS and it wants to create one but the deployment user account can't do that.

Comment: @juunas I have a virtual application specified: **/backend** maps to **site\wwwroot\backend**. Maybe I should change it to a virtual directory instead of an application?

Comment: It's been a long time since I tried virtual directories so I can't say directly what the problem is. Have you looked at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/?

Comment: I think I have it set up correctly. When I publish manually from VS 2017 using the same publish profile, the publish is successful and my app runs inside the **backend** folder.

Comment: If VS does it correctly, check the command it is using from the build logs :)

Comment: For task issue, you can submit a issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. According to [this answer by @starian chen-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870549/3053082), I needed to set the correct parameter in `SetParameters.xml`. I did this by adding the following to my Visual Studio Build task:

```
/p:DeployIisAppPath="xyz"
```

where `xyz` is the value of `DeployIisAppPath` element in the publish profile.

Comment: Somehow this did not work for me: changes to this build parameter or the passed xml to the deployment task causes no change to that site parameter shown in the deployment log. Any idea? I did also use the clean option in the build.

Comment: `xyz` usually matches Web App name as well. When I had to deploy to virtual directory under Web App, I had to change it to `xyz\v2`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that Azure expecting that site name will be presented twice in `scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=%SiteNameHere%"` and the same value as a parameter, by default value from file `SetParameters.xml` is used for second.

So, you need to modify the value of IIS Web Application Name parameter in xxx.SetParameters.xml programming (e.g. PowerShell or other tasks), after that it should works fine.

Azure staging web deploy fails with [ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP but not for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620562/azure-staging-web-deploy-fails-with-error-user-not-authorized-for-createapp-but?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks so much! I was investigating the problem for 4 days on row in Azure Pipelines! At last, I used a Powershell script task for replace the value in SetParameters.xml