# Where does that msdeploy.axd?site= param value come from?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, msdeploy

In Azure DevOps, my *continuous deployment pipeline fails* running the msdeploy command. The build does not throw any error. This is the error during the release deployment:

```
Error Code: ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP
```

Yes, very common, its the [site name missmatch problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854434/version-4-of-azure-app-service-deploy-error-user-not-authorized-for-createapp). But I did not manage to change that site URL parameter.
My local build and the locally run deployment command to deploy to Azure (to the Application service: xxxx-dev-app) works.
Locally the parameter `?site=` is not showing up and it works, if I manually modify the deployment script and add the `?site=` I can reproduce the same error with my locally run deployment script.

So, why is this parameter added to the Url during the Azure build and where does it get its value from?

**a)** My **parameters.xml** looks like this:

```
<parameters>
<parameter name="IIS Web Application Name" devaultValue="Default Web Site" />
</parameters>
```

**Result: no effect** on the site parameter value.

**b)** I tried setting the site name by running the MS build with these parameters:

> /p:IisApp="Default Web Site" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"

**Result: no effect** on the site parameter value.

**c)** I tried setting these variables in the Release Pipeline:[image]

**Result: no effect** on the site parameter value.

But the log output of the Azure Release deployment process always shows this URL:

> -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://xxx-dev-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=xxxx-dev-app'

If I directly modify the parameters.xml like this:

```
<parameters>
<setParameter name="IIS Web Application Name" value="Default Web Site" />
</parameters>
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Source does not support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name'.
```

*Appendix, 20.4.2019:*
After removing the parameters.xml and the variable 'IIS Web Application Name' I get still get this deploy output log line, showing that it tries to set the `?site=xxxx-dev-app` parameter:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
-verb:sync 
-source:package='d:\a\r1\a\xxxx CI Pipeline\xxxxToolV01\src\xxxxoolV01\xxxxoolV01\Publish\xxxxoolV01.zip' 
-dest:auto,
      ComputerName='https://xxxx-dev-app.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=xxxx-dev-app',
      UserName='$xxxx-dev-app',
      Password='***',
      AuthType='Basic'
-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='xxxx-dev-app'
-enableRule:AppOffline
-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
-userAgent:VSTS_b7d1246f-0592-4548-9a3d-da995f3fb94e_release_1_59_59_5
```

Comment: Did you try just deleting `parameters.xml`? If you're not doing deployment-time configuration transform, you don't need it. And if all you're setting is connection strings and app settings, you should be defining those on your azure web app instead of storing them in a web.config/appsettings.json, anyway.

Comment: Right. You don't need to specify that value if you remove the `parameters.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMann for that advice, I am really running out of ideas. But even after removing the release pipeline variables and the file `parameters.xml` it gives me the log output: `Error: Source does not support parameter called 'IIS Web Application Name'`

Comment: "IIS Web Application Name" is kind of hard coded in the msdeploy command. It seems to be requested to be part of the passed parameters.xml.